# Get frame rate of swf file using c++ builder

Tags: c++, binary, flash, c++builder

I need an example of parsing swf file header in C++ builder.

Answer (score 0):

The framerate is stored in the header. Just index to the correct position in the binary file and read the value.

http://www.the-labs.com/MacromediaFlash/SWF-Spec/SWFfileformat.html